# Persistent issue with Xam.Forms Lab on Android

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I have a multiplatform app using Xamarin.Forms. While I can build for iOS and WindowsPhone 8.1, when I build for Android, I get the following build error

`/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets: error : Error executing task LinkAssemblies: error XA2006: Reference to metadata item 'System.Void Android.OS.BaseBundle::PutString(System.String,System.String)' (defined in 'XLabs.Platform.Droid, Version=2.0.5679.29813, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null') from 'XLabs.Platform.Droid, Version=2.0.5679.29813, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' could not be resolved.`

I've searched around for a solution on this but cannot seem to find one or where on earth in my code this problem is coming from.

Does anyone know how to start solving this issue so I can submit a build?

Answer (score 0):

Check that the Xamarin Forms NuGet package versions are the same in the XLabs version you are using and the Android Project. Normally a version mismatch is the cause for these errors.

Comment: I would hope that as the 1.5 branch has been out now for quite a while that X.Labs would have recompiled against it. There is certainly no issues on the iOS side of things when building.

Comment: 1.5 initially came out on the 16th Sept, with an update on the 22nd. XLabs - Core 2.0.5743-pre8 was released on the 25th of Sept. So it could have been. But I would download and check the source code for its dependencies. XLabs is a community project that has intermittent maintenance.